# I need the syntax for sending a server commands from the client in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, inputstream, outputstream

I'm clearly missing something with network programming. I'm trying to write a program that sends a command to the server to perform a specific query on a sqlite database that is maintained on the server side. I want all SQL queries on the server side as well.

I need different methods to perform different functions by sending commands to a server. The only way I can establish a connection from the client side is by creating a new socket and input/output streams within the method, but I will have many, many methods corresponding to each button click on the GUI from the client side.

Is there a way I can use a single socket, and a single set of input/output streams to write these commands to the server, and reuse them? And if not, **what do I do to make this work over and over for each button click.**

I've gotten this working already but here's what it looks like:

**For Clients Side**

A method call to build a table of apartment tenants is called, command might be "1":

```
buildData(command)
```

within buildData:

```
public void buildData(String command, TableView table){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localHost", 5000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            out.writeUTF(command);

            System.out.println("Build Data Success");
            System.out.println(in.readObject());






        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Server Side**

```
private static String tenantQuery = "SELECT * FROM tenants;";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);
        Socket conn = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        while(true){
            command = input.readUTF();
            switch (command){
                case "1":
                    returned = buildData(tenantQuery);
                    out.writeObject(returned);

            }
        }


    }
```

And then in the corresponding server method buildData(query):

```
public static ArrayList<String> buildData(String query){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:FinalRental.db");
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                data.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS!!!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

From what I can tell, if I were to do this and need to have functionality to then ADD a tenant into the tenant table, I would need to create a new socket, input/output streams in what would become an addTenant() method later on when a hypothetical "Add Tenant" button is pushed in the GUI.

**Just to reiterate**

**What I've tried:**

Creating one socket and set of output/input streams, but I couldn't use the input/output streams everywhere in the code.

**The Problem:**

I don't know how to use one socket and set of input/output streams to do many things, or if this is even a possibility.

**Question:**

How do I set up a client/server relationship so that I can get data from a database on the server and return it to the client to dynamically populate a GUI display on the client side?

Comment: you may want to consider a REST service or a simple JSON response instead of sockets

Comment: @fantaghirocco I'm seeing that what I'm doing is not going to make sense. Any resources on either of those things?

Comment: you can google "restful webservice tutorial": internet is full of resorces about the topic. You may 1st want to have a look at what a restful ws is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer to check if it really can suit your needs